# How to display an array of bytes in PowerShell as a joined string of hex digits?

Tags: powershell, fiber

I am using WMI to find out what my WWN (World Wide Name) is for my port on an HBA card. I can get the WWN back but it is contained as an 8 byte array.  I would like to convert this byte array into a string of 16 hex digits for easy display.

This is the query I am using to print out each number in its own line.  Is there a way to convert this to have the 8 lines combined onto a single line?

```
gwmi -namespace root\wmi -class MSFC_FibrePortNPIVAttributes | select -expand WWPN | foreach { $_.ToString("X2") }
```

I think the following can be used to test with just the byte data but I'm still new to PowerShell.

```
[byte[]] 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 | foreach { $_.ToString("X2") }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a few ways (I'm sure there are others):

```
[byte[]](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) | foreach { $string = $string + $_.ToString("X2") }
Write-Output $string
```

or

```
-join ([byte[]](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) |  foreach {$_.ToString("X2") } )
```

or

```
([byte[]](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) |  foreach { $_.ToString("X2") }) -join ""
```

Output for each of the above:

```
0102030405060708
```

Comment: This lead me down the correct path.  I ended up with the following command that does what I need.

    gwmi -namespace root\wmi -class MSFC_FibrePortNPIVAttributes | select WWPN | foreach {[array]::Reverse($_.WWPN); [BitConverter]::ToUInt64($_.WWPN, 0).ToString("X") }

Answer (score 5):

One way you could do it is like so:

```
[System.BitConverter]::ToString([Byte[]](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)) -replace "-"
```

Here's a breakdown:

```
[Byte[]](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

This creates a ByteArray with 8 elements, each containing the value 1 through 8 respectively.

```
[System.BitConverter]::ToString(<ByteArray type Object>)
```

This converts the ByteArray to a dash-delimited string as so:

```
01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08
```

Lastly,

```
-replace "-"
```

This removes the dash.

Comment: Can you explain what this does?

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.